# Show that $ (B - A) \cup (C - A) = (B \cup C) - A$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I know that if we use defined and not abstract symbols and values that this makes sense, but I don't know how to prove it using symbols and stuff.

for example;
let A = {1}
    B = {1,2}
    C = {1,3,4}
if we use them in the formula, we get:
 $(\{1,2\} - \{1\}) \cup (\{1,3,4\} - \{1\}) = \{2\} U \{3,4\} = {2,3,4}$ ,
 which is what we would get if we did $(B \cup C) - A$

Can someone explain how I can show this without me having to use a long example with numbers instead of variables? How can we prove this in a more abstract way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you've already derived some handy rules for manipulating sets, the main way you prove two sets are equal is to show that they are subsets of each other - usually by proving that any element of one is also an element of the other.

In this case, let $x \in (B - A) \cup (C - A)$. That means that either $x \in B - A$ or $x \in C - A$. Let's suppose that $x \in B - A$. That means that $x \in B$ and $x \not\in A$. Which means that $x \in B \cup C$ and $x \not\in A$, which therefore means that $x \in (B \cup C) - A$. And be symmetry, the same is true if $x \in C - A$. So any element of the left hand side is also an element of the right hand side, meaning that $(B - A) \cup (C - A) \subseteq (B \cup C) - A$.

Similarly, you can show that the right side is a subset of the left side, and hence conclude that the two sets are equal.

When doing this, though, you may have to check that nothing breaks down when either set is empty (since you can't actually take an element from the empty set). Thankfully, that's not a problem in this instance but I'll leave that to you to check.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot prove it with examples.

Let $x$ belong to the left side. Then $x \in B, x\notin A, x\in C$. Hence $x \in B \cup C$ and $x\notin A$ so $x$ belongs to the right side. I will leave the reverse inclusion to you.